# How to set up composer.json to navigate to another directory and run a script there while running "composer install"

Tags: windows, composer-php

I'm building an admin dashboard using Laravel Nova. There, custom tools are being generated in nova-components directory. I have created a tool called "Team Dashboard" and in that team dashboard folder, there is a separate composer.json file & package.json file. To build assests, I have to run "npm run production".

What I want to is, run "npm run production" from Team Dashboard folder when I run "composer install" command from root folder. For that, I add the following lines to composer.json file in root. See "post-install-cmd".

```
"scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force",
            "npm install",
            "npm run production"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "cd nova-components/TeamDashboard npm run production",
            "npm install",
            "npm run production"
        ]
    },
```

When executing `"cd nova-components/TeamDashboard npm run production"` part, composer says `The system cannot find the path specified.`.

How I can implement such a case in composer.json.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: perhaps: `"@php -r \"chdir('nova-components/TeamDashboard') && passthru('npm run production') && exit(0) || exit(1);\""`; compare with the answer of _Nico Haase_ [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73113612/367456)

Comment: @hakre Windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cd nova-components/TeamDashboard npm run production`  tries to use `cd`  with all these arguments. It does not execute the parts after the path.

`cd nova-components/TeamDashboard && npm run production` could work, as it runs `cd`  first, and `npm`  afterwards